# Best place to add analytics in ApostropheCMS

Tags: google-analytics, apostrophe-cms

I am trying to get tracking in place and was wondering what will be the best place to add the JS code. Also need to make sure that is it not getting minified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest extending outerLayout.html in `lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/views/outerLayout.html`. In this template, you can modify the `extraHead` block like so:

```
{% extends "outerLayoutBase.html" %}

{% block extraHead %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '...']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the block where I typically put things like favicon definitions, open graph meta tags, remote font loading, and all that good stuff.

Comment: looks like this works for me. It will be nice to see the JS code at the end of the page instead of the beginning.

Comment: The end of the page is easy too. Take a look at the blocks in `outerLayoutBase` that you can override, notably `afterMain` and `extraBody`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - may be a good idea to do the analytics ID (etc) as a global so your user can set it there self. Note that this will impact performance a little as it'll be requested for each page, but it can be really useful. And don't forget to wrap the script in `{% if data.global.analyticsID %}`!